# sort nested timestamps in a query

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I need to make a query with a list of `Incidents` and his nested `events` ordered DESC by his `startedAt` and `timestamp` dates. By default ReQL give the dates with a ASC order. I've got the folowing structure:

`{
  "id":  "87e14db8-1e15-4718-baac-f1c785e985cb" , 
  "title":  "Connection Error"
  "startedAt": Mon Oct 26 2015 14:33:00 GMT+00:00 ,
  "events": [{
    "message": "Cannot connect to theserver.com",
    "timestamp": Mon Oct 26 2015 14:33:00 GMT+00:00
  },{
    "message": "Cannot connect to theserver.com,"
    "timestamp": Mon Oct 26 2015 14:33:20 GMT+00:00
  },{
    "message": "Cannot connect to theserver.com",
    "timestamp": Mon Oct 26 2015 14:33:40 GMT+00:00
  }]
},{
  "id":  "87e14db8-1e15-4718-baac-f1c785e985cb" , 
  "title":  "Other Connection Error"
  "startedAt": Mon Oct 26 2015 14:34:20 GMT+00:00 ,
  "events": [{
    "message": "Connection rejected",
    "timestamp": Mon Oct 26 2015 14:34:20 GMT+00:00
  },{
     "message": "Connection rejected",
     "timestamp": Mon Oct 26 2015 14:34:41 GMT+00:00
  }]
},{
 ... (several more)
}`

If I run `r.db('mydb').table('Incident').orderBy(r.desc('createdAt'))`, the Incident's are ordered by `createdAt` as espected. But the nested `events`are still ordered ASC.

How can I make a query in order to get the nested events with a DESC order by timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
r.table('Incident').orderBy(r.desc('createdAt')).merge(function(row) {
  return {events: row('events').orderBy(r.desc('timestamp'))};
})
```

Comment: It works perfectly!! I must check more deep that merge method, somethimes do things in rethinkdb is hard because SQL mind-set, but in the long run I love it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for. Just took a little wizardy with the `.map(...)` method.

```
r.db("test").table("stackoverflow").orderBy(r.desc('startedAt')).map(function(d){
  return {
    "startedAt":d("startedAt"),
    "title": d("title"),
    "id": d("id"),
    "events": d("events").orderBy(r.desc("timestamp"))
  }
})
```

Comment: Bah, @mlucy beat me to it. And `.merge(...)` works a lot better here rather than constructing a new object to return within the anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks @dalanmiller, is good to see another way of doing it :)